# how to inject uppercaseFilter in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to inject uppercase filter as dependency injection to controller , I tried injecting the orderByFilter and it worked flawlessly.
you can refer to my sample Plunker project

[PlunkerLink](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ja9oLMMLs9Dk3n8bOloS?p=preview)

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller('HomeController',function($scope,orderByFilter,uppercaseFilter)
{
  $scope.sortOrder = '-id';
  $scope.upperCase = 'fName';
   $scope.users = [
    { id: 1, fName: 'Hege', lName: "Pege" },
    { id: 2, fName: 'Kim', lName: "Pim" },
    { id: 3, fName: 'Jack', lName: "Jones" },
    { id: 4, fName: 'John', lName: "Doe" },
    { id: 5, fName: 'Peter', lName: "Pan" }
];
 $scope.users = orderByFilter($scope.users, $scope.sortOrder);
 $scope.users = uppercaseFilter($scope.users, $scope.upperCase);

});
```

Comment: `uppercaseFilter` works on a string, not an array. You need to iterate over the array on your own, applying the filter (or just doing the native `.toUpperCase()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to process array of object manually, as upperCase filter works on strings only. In your case it can be like this for example:

```
$scope.users = $scope.users.map(function(obj) {
    obj[$scope.upperCase] = obj[$scope.upperCase].toUpperCase();
    return obj;
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/QaCisLJAUI1eWbZNTtdz?p=preview

Comment: obj[$scope.upperCase] = uppercaseFilter(obj[$scope.upperCase]) would be more appropriate given that he was trying to inject the filter, no? Or easier still it would be be easier to just suffix the "| uppercase" to the template

Comment: yes, you are right, I just wanted to demonstrate that uppercaseFilter is nothing more but just a corresponding method.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you.

HTML code-sample

```
<span>{{ users.fName | limitTo : 3 | uppercase }}</span>
<span ng-bind="users.fName | limitTo : 3 | uppercase "></span>
```

AngularJs code-sample

```
<script>
  angular.module("myApp").controller("myController"), function($filter){

    var result = $filter(‘limitTo’)(users.fName, 3);
    $filter(‘uppercase’)(result);
    ...
  }
</script>
```